# Is it safe to install software globally with npm?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, npm

The node.js package manager, `npm`, has an option to install packages globally. Since distributions typically have their own package manager, is it safe to use the global option? Could `npm` packages conflict with distribution packages and cause errors down the road that are hard to trace back?

Comment: To be picky, that's the *node.js* package manager.  Have a look here: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html for the relevance of global vs. local.  I would guess if `npm` is from a distro package, its prefix will be `/usr` whereas if you built from source it's `/usr/local/` -- if you have both, that's then two separate places for modules installed *globally* to end up.  Calling `node` on the command line will most likely default to the `/usr/local` one, and it will not have access to any modules installed globally by the distro one...

Comment: ...That doesn't deal with the issue of using `npm` globally vs. installing node packages from the distro.  I would guess for the distro version of `npm` they would conflict, or rather, install overtop.  Probably using `npm` gets you the more recent version.

Comment: @goldilocks I only have `npm` installed from my distribution's package manager so we don't have to worry about there being two `npm` binaries behaving differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how `npm` was configured when it was installed.

If `npm` was installed [on Debian from the package that is included in the distribution](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/npm), then, yes, it is safe. `npm` with the global option installs to `/usr/local`, which is explicitly set aside for local software installation and should not conflict with the operating system distribution's own installations.

`npm -g` installs to `/usr/local` (`/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc...) even if `npm` itself is located in `/usr/bin` as it would be if it were itself installed from, say, a Debian package that's part of the OS distribution.

Most likely there are other operating system distributions to which the above applies.

On Fedora on the other hand, `npm` installs packages to `/usr/lib/node_modules` (not in `/usr/local`). I don't know whether or not this is safe. It depends if any Fedora-packaged nodejs modules also go to `/usr/lib/node_modules` or whether they go somewhere else. If they go somewhere else, then it would be safe.

Comment: Hmm.. This doesn't seem to be the case for my system (Fedora 19).  `which npm` gives `/usr/bin/npm`, but checking in `/usr/local`, I don't see any directories corresponding to `npm` modules I've installed.

Comment: My answer is based on my experience with Debian jessie (the earliest Debian distribution which contains `npm`). I'm surprised to hear it's different on Fedora. Are you able to find where your packages that were installed using `npm -g` did go?

Comment: @Caleda It looks like the ones I've installed are under `/usr/lib/node_modules/`

Comment: I see. Looks like I have to edit my answer.